# SSO to User Progress page in D2L LMS

Tags: desire2learn

Is it possible to SSO directly to the user progress page in D2L LMS. The current SSO functionality can take me to the main home page or the Course home page if I supply the org unit id of the course. However I want the parents to go directly to user progress page. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to SSO to the User Progress page in the upcoming Fall 2012 release (v10.2.0); however, it will not work properly with prior releases.

Comment: - Can you provide me some insight on how to SSO to the user progress page?

Comment: Once you have an LMS version where the progress page supports this deep-linking, you should use the same technique to reach it that you would other deep-link-able pages (such as course home page).